# How to test if Action<...> is null?

Tags: c#, .net, null, functional-programming, nullreferenceexception

Suppose I have a function that looks like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Action<object> something)
{
    something(getObject());
}
```

If `something` is null, then this code will raise a NullReferenceException.

However, `something == null` will not compile, so how do I test `something` to find out if it is null?

Comment: You should be able to check if it is null, what is the actual compiler error you get when you try `something == null`?

Comment: `someting == null` is correct. Are you sure you're not accidentally typing `something() == null`?

Comment: Nevermind that, I must have typoed something because now `something == null` will compile.

Comment: I just had this, it's a Visual Studio bug. if you build it disappears

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to test against null directly.  This compiles fine:

```
public void DoSomething(Action<object> something)
{
    if (something == null) // Note that there are no () on something
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("something");
    }

    something(GetObject()); // Assumes `GetObject()` method is available on class, etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(something == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("something");
}
```

This should work great as a first block of your method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
if(something == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("something");
```

I can't see a reason why this wouldn't compile?

Answer (score 1):

How did you write your "something == null" statement?  The below compiles for me and I think you can tweak it a bit to have appropriate if/else conditions.

```
    public void DoSomething(Action<object> something)
    {
        if (something != null)
        {
            something(getObject());
        }
    }
```